# Powershell 4.0 can't import hash table from psm1

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to import a hash table from psm1 but it returns blank no errors, I'm using windows server 2012 r2, while on my machine with powershell 5.1 it works with no issues, am I doing something wrong or it's not supported in 4.0?

**psm1**

```
$hash =@{ 
    SomeKey = 'SomeValue'
    SomeKey2 = 'SomeValue2'
    SomeKey3 = 'SomeValue3'
}
```

**ps1**

```
Import-Module .\hash.psm1
$hash
```

Comment: _How_? By dot-sourcing the psm1? Using `Import-Module`? `Export-ModuleMember`? Hard to say whether what you're doing is wrong without knowing what you're doing :)

Comment: Is it a hashtable or a PSCustomObject? With PS4 you need to use `New-Object psobject` while with PS5 you can just write `[PSCustomObject]{...}`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm using Import-Module

Comment: `Import-Module` either returns _nothing_, or a module info object pertaining to the imported module, so it's still unclear to me what you're doing - please update the post with the contents of your module file?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Updated

Comment: @Alex_P AFAIK the `[PSCustomObject]` was introduced in PowerShell 3.0

Comment: @BugsBunny along with the current answer you have, if you change `$hash` to `$global:hash` it will get defined in the global scope no matter how it is called. You can also try `Import-Module -scope Global`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with powershell 5.1 it works with no issues

I was unable to produce the desired behavior with 5.1

In any case, you need to export the containing variable from the module:

```bsh
$hash =@{ 
    SomeKey = 'SomeValue'
    SomeKey2 = 'SomeValue2'
    SomeKey3 = 'SomeValue3'
}

Export-ModuleMember -Variable hash
```

Comment: Thanks, the Export-ModuleMember -Variable was what I needed